# Unable to get data from previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I wanted to get two String value from the second activity back to the first activity after the second activity `finish();`. I tried using the below code and there is no error and I can't get the return value as well.

**Activity A**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activityA.this, activityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                 int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult");
    if(resultCode == 100){
        Bundle res = data.getExtras();
         String contentid = res.getString("contentID");
         String contenttype = res.getString("contentType");
         Log.i(TAG, "contentid:" +contentid);
         Log.i(TAG, "contenttype:" +contenttype);
    }
}
```

**Activity B**

```
 @Override
 public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
     helper.close();
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.putExtra("contentID", contentID);
     intent.putExtra("contentType", contentType);
     setResult(100, intent);
     Log.i(TAG, "SETRESULT.................." +intent);
     finish();
 }
```

Any comment or answer will be appreciated.

Comment: you are getting `Log.i(TAG, "SETRESULT.................." +intent);` log in logcat ?

Comment: Yep... SETRESULT.......................Intent{ (has extras) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize what is wrong with my code. I should not `SETRESULT` at `onDestroy()`. If I place it elsewhere, it worked. Sorry and thank you for your time

Comment: That's right but not enough. Here's [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). I hope it'd be useful…